# Using a lock in a Jenkins Workflow Job

Tags: jenkins, build, locking, jenkins-workflow

I want to use a lock in a workflow job in order to prevent jobs from running at the same time on the same node.

I want to use the functionality of the lock and latches plugin to control the parallel execution of jobs: When a Job A starts building on a specific node, Job B should wait until A is done, and then B can run.

How can I achieve that ? or is there another solution (in case locks are not supported in workflow jobs) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to prevent? The easiest way would be to set each node as having only 1 executor... If you do this, then the node will only ever run one job at a time. Note that some fly-weight tasks may run but generally these are non-significant and involve polling the remote SCM repository and such.

If you just mean within the same workflow, you can use various mix of the parallel step to split parallel sections and then combine the results.

Comment: I want to use the functionality of the lock and latches plugin to control the parallel execution of jobs: When a Job A starts building on a specific node, Job B should wait until A is done, and then B can run.